# how to add sorting function in repeater in asp 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I m using asp 2.0, I need an requirement for sorting the repeater control. I search over the Internet but i could nt find the correct solution. If anyone knows the answer please help to solve my problem.

Comment: If anyone have simple solution for sorting function then give your suggestion.See my answer.

Comment: if anyone give negative points, please explain the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got the Sorting output in Repeater Control.

1.Maintaining the Static Variable;

```
static int count = 0;
```

2.In LinkButton click Event

```
protected void lnkreq_name_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   count=Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"].ToString());
   ViewState["count"] = count;
   loadRepeater("REQUEST_NAME",count);
}
```

3.call the Function

```
protected void loadRepeater(string reqname,int count)
{
     //write the code to bind into Dataset

     DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
     if (count  == 0)
     {
         dv.Sort = reqname + " asc";
         ViewState["count"] = 1;
      }
      else if (count == 1)
      {
          dv.Sort = reqname + " desc";
          ViewState["count"] = 0;
       }

       //then bind into repeater
}
```

4.In Repeater

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RepeaterEntry" >
 <HeaderTemplate >
<table class="list_table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<th><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkreq_name" runat="server" ForeColor="white" OnClick="lnkreq_name_click" >Request Name</asp:LinkButton></th>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>

 <ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td><%# Eval("REQUEST_NAME")%></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I think this code may be one of the solution for Sorting Function in Repeater Control.I m accepted this not the best solution for Sorting Option.If anyone have simple solution for sorting function then give your suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

You need to sort the collection before binding to the repeater.

If you want to dynamically sort on post backs, sort in the event handler before re-binding to the repeater.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/paging-and-sorting-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/sorting-data-in-a-datalist-or-repeater-control-cs) article explains how to add sort functionality to a Repeater or a DataList control. It might help to your purpose or at least as a guide.

Comment: i m using queries to bind the data into Dataset and then assigned into repeater control. But this article is using sqldatasource. how to do sorting in my repeater control..